# Flutter ListTile with empty title - is it possible?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to have `ListTile` widget that sometimes has `title` as null, e.g.:

```
ListTile(
  title: item.title.isNotEmpty
    ? Text(
        item.title,
        maxLines: 1,
      )
    : null,
subtitle: Text(
        task.text,
        maxLines: 3,
        overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
      ),
}
```

If the `title` is null, it stays there as an empty space, which causes entire widget to look ugly.

On the other hand, if the subtitle is null, it nicely collapse.

[image]

Comment: so what exactly do you want if the title is NULL ? You could pass the subtitle as title instead then?

Comment: @OMiShah - in that case I want to have title collapsed and subtitle be shown in smaller, greyish font... which I can do putting it in title. True. Just hacky. But fine ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the `subtitle` text on `title` place when `title` is empty.

```dart
ListTile(
  title:Text(
        item.title.isNotEmpty? item.title : task.text,
        maxLines: 1,
      ), 
  subtitle: item.title.isNotEmpty? Text(
        task.text,
        maxLines: 3,
        overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
      ): null,
}
```

Comment: This will work, however styles will be different. The `subtitle` text in `title` will display with `title`'s bigger font. I guess some manual style adjustment is needed, right?

Comment: yes if you wish to have that. you can use same ternary for TextStyle

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can.

You have an error in your code, you closed your ListTitle with this '}', replace it with ')'.

Result will be:

```
ListTile(
  title: item.title.isNotEmpty
    ? Text(
        item.title,
        maxLines: 1,
      )
    : null,
  subtitle: Text(
    task.text,
    maxLines: 3,
    overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
  ),
)
```

Comment: i think you should read the question again and whether the title is null or not, it'll always take space !

Comment: True, I have bug in my example, but your answer doesn't answer the question.